# A question on the level set of real analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a non-constant real analytic function on a compact set $\Omega$. Denote $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $a\in$Im$f$, we know that
$$\mu(\{x\in\Omega:f(x)=a\})=0.$$

Is it true that

$$\mu(\{x\in\Omega:a-\epsilon\leq f\leq a+\epsilon\})\rightarrow 0\quad \mathrm{as\ } \epsilon\rightarrow 0^+?$$

---

Added: originally the question I asked was on $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, now I changed it to  $f:\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ where $\Omega$ is a compact set.

Comment: If $\Omega$ is compact you can just appeal to "continuity from above" for finite measures.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the case $f(x) = \sin x$. For each $a$ in the range of $f$, the set $f^{-1}(a)$ is countable so that $\mu(f^{-1}(a)) = 0$.

On the other hand, $f^{-1}((a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon))$ consists of infinitely many disjoint translates of an interval of positive length, so $\mu(f^{-1}(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)) = \infty$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

So no, the limit isn't necessarily $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I changed my question.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the original question about $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$:

No. Take $n=1$. Let $f(x)=xe^{x}$. Let $a=0$. For every $\epsilon>0$ the set where $|f|\le\epsilon$ has infinite measure.

Answer to the revised question:

Yes. The set where $f=a$ has measure zero. It is the intersection of the sets where $|f-a|<\le1/j$, $j=1,2,\dots$. Since $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$ the measure of the set where $|f-a|\le1/j$ tends to $0$, by "continuity from above" for measures.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I changed my question.